# C++ Initialize Static Array

Tags: c++, arrays, static

I am not sure that this is even possible. From all the examples I have seen, the array is defined within the `{ }` brackets, but in my case it is not much possible.

What I am trying to do is keep this in my drawing function to draw multiple circles that slowly increase in size.

What I am getting by using a debugger is the static array is being reset every time the loop hits.

I have also tried something like `static Rect rc[5] = {}`

```
void fun_called_every_five_seconds() {
     static Rect rc[5];

     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         int x = rand()%400;
         int y = rand()%400;
         int r = rand()%200;
         rc[i] = Rect (x,y,r,r);
     }

     rc[0].X += 50;


     // I check value of rc[0].X right here
 }
```

Comment: In what context is the code? Are both the code and the `static` array inside a function, or is the `static` in the namespace scope? Please give a [MCVE]

Comment: @KABoissonneault added the example. From a timer that function is called every 5 seconds.

Comment: The `for` loop will execute every time you call the function.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp because this array is not needed on a larger scope (global the next option?), is there anyway to fill the array only once? I thought normally you can do that, like `static int = 5;`

Comment: Looks like what you're trying to do is implement a Singleton pattern with a single point of initialization. Currently, the code does not check if the singleton `rc` has been initialized already, and you end up resetting it on each function call.

Comment: `static int s_something = 5;` only works because it's initialization, you can't reinitialize and so the value won't "switch back" if it's been re defined somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, gave me this idea, how is it? I used: `static Rect rc[5] = {}` and then added this if statement between the for loop: `if (rc[0].X == 0) {`, It works in this case because it should never be 0. But this could act different in different cases because I never actually set it to 0 and could be a different value on a different computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the static array is being reset every time the loop hits

well yes, your loop explicitly resets the static array.

The minimal change is to just run the initialization loop once:

```
void for_fun_called_every_five_seconds() {
    static Rect rc[5];
    static bool init = false;
    if (!init) { // this only happens once
        init = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int x = rand()%400;
            int y = rand()%400;
            int r = rand()%200;
            rc[i] = Rect (x,y,r,r);
        }
    }

    rc[0].X += 50;

    // I check value of rc[0].X right here
}
```

but this is pretty ugly, and unnecessarily hard to reason about. Prefer something like

```
class Circles {
    Rect rc[5];
public:
    Circles() {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int x = rand()%400;
            int y = rand()%400;
            int r = rand()%200;
            rc[i] = Rect (x,y,r,r);
        }
    }
    void for_fun_called_every_five_seconds() {
        // should this also be in a loop,
        // ie. each rc[i] gets increased?
        rc[0].X += 50;
        // I check value of rc[0].X right here
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice, that solution works. If my program (game) wasn't already bogged down with classes, I would opt for the latter.

Comment: Might also want to use the facilities in [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) if you want better/portable random number generation

Comment: @EvanCarslake: You aren't creating new classes because you have used up your arbitrary quota of classes per project? Seriously?

Comment: Note that the first solution is not thread-safe. Also, @EvanCarslake, I don't think there is such a thing as too many classes. Classes in C++ can be "zero overhead" abstractions, meaning that they are free tools for you to use, without pessimizing the execution of your program. If a class can help you hide some complex logic in a simple interface, then you should always do so.

Comment: @llnspectable well, really what I meant is that my main drawing function is pretty enormous and these specific draw parts I would like compact within. For example, this is an animation that changes on every different level. I guess I could make a class to handle all of that...

Comment: Factoring things out into small classes doesn't make your _main drawing function_ bigger, it makes it smaller. You probably just need to factor _more_ stuff out of there into simple functions or classes.

Comment: @EvanCarslake Sounds like you need to refactor and break up your code some more.  Compilers are really good at taking small functions that make looking at your code make a lot of sense and inline them all away to make the code as fast as possible.  Really you want to write for maintainability and only start performance tuning once you have compiled and profiled and found something lacking.

Answer (score 4):

You can split your code and put the array initialization elsewhere:

```
auto make_rect_array() {
    std::array<Rect, 5> rc;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int x = rand()%400; // you may want better random
        int y = rand()%400;
        int r = rand()%200;

        rc[i] = Rect (x,y,r,r);
    }

    return rc;
}
```

Then, just call that in your function:

```
void fun_called_every_five_seconds() {
    static auto rc = make_rect_array();

    rc[0].X += 50;
    // I check value of rc[0].X right here
}
```

That way, you don't introduce an additional branch in your code, it look much cleaner and it's thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to be surprised about here. Every time a function is called, all its code is executed from its arguments.
The only exception here would be the initialization of a `static` variable, which is guaranteed to run only once during the lifetime of the program (also thread-safe since C++11).
The initialization of a variable only happens during its definition, on the very line you give your variable the name in this context. All the code after that is simply "mutating" your variable to give it the value you wanted to: it is not initialization.

There are two solutions here. Either you use `std::call_once` with a lambda (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) to make the "initialization" code run only once.
Or you somehow fit all that code in one line on the definition of the variable. It might be complicated for a C-style array, but not for a `std::array`, which can be easily returned from functions and be used to initialize an `std::array`.

```
std::array<Rect, 5> initialize_rc() {
   std::array<Rect, 5> rc;

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       int x = rand()%400;
       int y = rand()%400;
       int r = rand()%200;
       rc[i] = Rect (x,y,r,r);
   }

   return rc;
}

void for_fun_called_every_five_seconds() {
   static std::array<Rect, 5> rc = initialize_rc();

   rc[0].X += 50;

   // I check value of rc[0].X right here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is fine, as long as the whole thing doesn't have to be thread-safe.

If the initialization must be thread safe, there's no alternative to shoving everything into the declaration.

However, a helper class can be used to minimize the typing:

```
class RandomRect : public Rect {

public:
    RandomRect() : RandomRect(rand() % 400, rand() % 400, rand % 200) {}
    RandomRect(int x, int y, int r) : Rect(x, y, r, r) {}
};

// ... Then, initialize the static array as follows:

static Rect rc[5]={RandomRect(), RandomRect(), RandomRect(),
                   RandomRect(), RandomRect()};
```